# Cannot get Nivo Slider to work

Tags: jquery, html, nivo-slider

I cannot seem to get the nivo slider to work. I have followed the instructions on their site to the letter.

Here is my `index.html`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function() {
                $('#slider').nivoSlider();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/nemo.jpg" alt="" />
                <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><img src="images/up.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" /></a>
                <img src="images/toystory.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" />
                <img src="images/walle.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
            <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my `style.css`.

```
.nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
.nivoSlider a {
    border:0;
    display:block;
}
```

I can't figure out why it is not working. I've also tried referencing the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: you'll need to be more specific that 'it is not working'...

Comment: Im sure your sources are not linked correctly. Using your html and pointing `<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />` to the right location it works fine.

Comment: are your all files in same folder?

Comment: @psycho, it works well for me. If you are using firefox, check the error in console by pressing Ctrl+Shift+J

Comment: chrome is telling me it failed to load resource file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js and file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js and file://localhost/Users/anchorman1986/Desktop/Slider%20Tutorial/jquery.nivo.slide‌​r.pack.js

Answer (score 0):

when you use jquery and you don't understand why it's not working use webdeveloper tools.

if you are using use firebug plugin or if you use chrome use inspected element tool. what they do they will tell you the error. this way you can understand what is going on and you can ask better questions.

Comment: chrome is telling me it failed to load resource file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js and file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js and file://localhost/Users/anchorman1986/Desktop/Slider%20Tutorial/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js

Comment: change file:// to http:// then please and let me know if it works, thick the answer. thanks.